# SQLITE: How to get RANK from a SELECT query result without using temporary table?

Tags: database, sqlite

everyone.
I have a table like this:

```
sqlite> select * from dayobs where year>=2015 and month=4 and days>=29 and station< 53333 limit 100;
station     year        month       days        rain        ave_temp    min_temp    max_temp    sunshine    date_ymd
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------------
53111       2015        4           29          0.0         212.0       96.0        315.0       121         04/29/15 00:00:00
53111       2015        4           30          4.0         181.0       124.0       264.0       48          04/30/15 00:00:00
53111       2016        4           29          0.0         201.0       94.0        302.0       120         04/29/16 00:00:00
53111       2016        4           30          0.0         187.0       107.0       263.0       41          04/30/16 00:00:00
53222       2015        4           29          0.0         198.0       118.0       277.0       122         04/29/15 00:00:00
53222       2015        4           30          17.0        141.0       86.0        225.0       2           04/30/15 00:00:00
53222       2016        4           29          0.0         193.0       110.0       274.0       114         04/29/16 00:00:00
53222       2016        4           30          0.0         190.0       122.0       256.0       78          04/30/16 00:00:00
```

(I use 'limit' and 'WHERE' clause to avoid printing out too many records, the table is very long.)

Now I want to get the rank of AVERAGE TEMPERATURE BETWEEN specified time window.

I can get the result by generate a temporary table by:

1,create a temporary table:

```
sqlite> create table s61 as
   ...> select station,year,avg(ave_temp)/10 as temp from dayobs where month=4 and days>29 and year>2013 and station<53333 group by station, year;
sqlite> select * from s61;
station     year        temp
----------  ----------  ----------
53111       2014        17.7
53111       2015        18.1
53111       2016        18.7
53222       2014        16.1
53222       2015        14.1
53222       2016        19.0
```

2,
get the rank from temporary table s61:

```
sqlite> select station,year,
   ...> temp,
   ...> (select count()+1 from s61 as r where r.temp<s61.temp and s61.station==r.station) as rank_t
   ...> from s61
   ...> where year==2015 group by station order by station;
station     year        temp        rank_t
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
53111       2015        18.1        2
53222       2015        14.1        1
```

this is exactly what I want.

**but my question is ,how to get this without this temporary table?** As this version of sqlite(version3.8.2 2013-12-06) doesn't support 'with' clause. And use a compound select will cause an error:

```
sqlite> select s61.station,
   ...> (select count()+1 from (select station,avg(dayobs.ave_temp)/10 as t61,sum(dayobs.rain)/10 as r61 from dayobs where month=5 and year>=2015 and days>=1 and days<=15 group by station,year) as r where r.t61 > s61.t61 and s61.station==r.station) as rantk_t
   ...> from (select station,avg(dayobs.ave_temp)/10 as t61,sum(dayobs.rain)/10 as r61 from dayobs where month=5 and year>=2015 and days>=1 and days<=15 group by station,year) as s61;
Error: misuse of aggregate: avg()
```

I don't want to create a temporary table and drop it everytime.
I also tried to use 'HAVING', but this is not what I expect:

```
select s61.station,s61.year,
(select count()+1 from tt as r group by year having r.t61 > s61.t61 and s61.station==r.station) as rantk_t
from (select station,year,avg(dayobs.ave_temp)/10 as t61,sum(dayobs.rain)/10 as r61 from dayobs where month=5 and year>=2015 and days>=1 and days<=15 group by station,year) as s61;
```

It seems that sqlite cannot use a SELECT result as the data source well. Any attempt of something like this will lead to an 'misuse of aggregate ' error:

select ....count()...
from (select .... ) as a_table;

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Write the query with WITH. Then manually replace those CTEs into the query as subqueries. Then consider whether updating SQLite wouldn't be a better idea.

Comment: thank u very much, I'm considering updating the default version of sqlite with ubuntu manually.

Answer (score 0):

after try and try I realized that maybe there are only 2 ways out:

- method 1:

  updating this version of sqlite3 to newest version, the new version
  has **WITH** clause. But before I try to updating the sqlite3, I think I can give method 2  a tyr:
- method 2:

  maybe it's something tricky but it works:

--ex5.sql:

```
select c.station,c.year,c.temp,count(s.station) as rank_t
    from
        (select station,year,avg(ave_temp)/10 as temp from dayobs where station<53333 and month=5 and year=2016 and days>=1 and days<=15 group by station,year) as c
            join
        (select station,year,avg(ave_temp)/10 as temp from dayobs where station<53333 and month=5 and year>=2010 and days>=1 and days<=15 group by station,year) as s
            on s.station==c.station
    where s.temp>=c.temp group by s.station;

select station,year,avg(ave_temp)/10 as temp from dayobs where station<53333 and month=5 and year>=2010 and days>=1 and days<=15 group by station,year;
```

you can see the result is exact what I expect:

```
sqlite> .read ex5.sql
station     year        temp        rank_t
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
53111       2016        15.74       5
53222       2016        13.3133333  6
station     year        temp
----------  ----------  ----------
53111       2010        17.28
53111       2011        15.6933333
53111       2012        18.5733333
53111       2013        18.2333333
53111       2014        14.3733333
53111       2015        16.4933333
53111       2016        15.74
53222       2010        15.1
53222       2011        13.6133333
53222       2012        15.3133333
53222       2013        15.8333333
53222       2014        12.4666666
53222       2015        14.72
53222       2016        13.3133333
```

this method avoids use COUNT() on a select result of a REFERENCE table.

Comment: It seems like there is a race condition in doing the subquery select twice.